# Erro no Arduino Leonardo ao compilar um codigo para o display tft 2.4 shield

Tags: arduino

Quando tento compilar qualquer código para o meu Arduino Leonardo acontece o seguinte erro com a maioria dos exemplos de bibliotecas que testei.(Essa biblioteca que eu testei foi a única que consegui achar que falam que funciona no arduino Leonardo, mas as outras da Adafruit davam erro do mesmo jeito):

> In file included from
>   C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SPFD5408-master\SPFD5408_Adafruit_TFTLCD.cpp:30:0:
>
> C:\Users\User\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SPFD5408-master\pin_magic.h:306:33:
>   warning: backslash and newline separated by space
>
> #define read8inline(result) { \

Fora que quando não acontece nenhum erro, dá tela branca do mesmo jeito, alguém já teve esse problema e conseguiu resolver? Ou o Arduino Leonardo é incompatível com a tela?

Answer (score 1):

Esta lib é de minha autoria, consegui alterando os códigos da Adafruit, para meu antigo TFT 2.4.

Porém isto só funciona com o controlador SPFD5408!
No segundo lote que comprei, isto não funcionou mais, os chineses mudaram para outro controlador.

Eu não testei no Leonardo. Sendo sincero, mesmo não dando erro, existe a possibilidade de continuar como a tela branca.
Tens um arduino uno ou mega para testar o TFT ?
Se funcionar com isto, posso ver o que ocorre com o AtMega32U4 (leonardo)

Eu atualmente não utilizo mais estes displays.
Utilizo o Nextion, um pouco mais caro, mas vale a pena:
  - Editor no PC (salva um sdcard e o TFT le isto e atualiza as telas)
  - 4 fios de conexão somente !

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mesmo, mas ja resolvi o problema baixei a propria lib do MCUFRIEND que era a marca do meu display